# How do you stop a Pharoah's Serpent reaction?

Tags: heat, decomposition

I am a novelist and working on a book. I have been searching google for an answer to the above question. How does one stop a Pharoah's Serpent reaction? Thanks!

Comment: Pharoah's serpent is the exothermic decomposition of Mercury(II) thiocyanate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury%28II%29_thiocyanate.   As it is strongly exothermic, I think it will be pretty hard to stop once initiated.

Comment: You don't. $\!$

Answer (score 3):

Just put water on it.  A temperature of $\pu{165^\circ C}$ is required to sustain the decomposition. Adding water will remove heat from the reaction and will dissolve a small amount of the mercury thiocyanate. The heat removed by heating and boiling the water will cool the contents below the decomposition temperature.  Adding soap will help the water penetrate into the powder and more quickly stop the reaction.

Comment: The water will rapidly vaporise, possibly creating a mercury-bearing aerosol. Bad idea.

Comment: I somehow think that a small amount of aerosol is likely not as bad as the additional fumes from a continued reaction.

Comment: I'm not sure it's small. Compare it with throwing water on hot oil: bad idea.

Comment: Water is denser than oil which causes the splattering of oil.  that mechanism is not available to a dense solid powder.

Comment: Can you give a reference that addresses the safety aspect?